# Taking an account on xbox 360 to ps3!

Tags: xbox-360

Can I take an account from a Xbox360 and use it on a PS3?

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot. The Xbox 360 and PS3 were made by two different companies and there is no cross feature for your Xbox 360 gamertag and Playstation Network profile.